# React changing background images using getElementById

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

There is soemthing weird happening with me in react
for some reason changing the background image of a div like that works:

```
document.getElementById("player1-card1").style.backgroundImage =
 `url(${require(../images/3.png)})`
```

But like that wont work

```
const y = 3
const x = `../images/${y}.png`
document.getElementById("player1-card1").style.backgroundImage =
 `url(${require(x)})`
```

x is the same value as ../images/3.png so why it is not working I am confused

Comment: You should almost never modify dom directly in react

Comment: @KonradLinkowski I am working with websockets So I have to get images from the database throught async methods so i have no other choice. Fortunatly it finally works i am posting the answer in a bit

Comment: You should create a state and change it when a message arrives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be using document.getElementById in React. If you want to set the style in react, import the image and then just pass it into the style prop.

```
import img from "../images/3.png"

<div style={{backgroundImage: img}}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't remember how websockets api looks like, but your code should utilize state like that:

```
const Component = () => {
  const [image, setImage] = useState();
  useEffect(() => {
    socket.onMessage = (data) => {
      setImage(data)
    }
  })
  return <div style={{ backgroundImage: image }} />
}
```

Comment: My problem is not with websockets, I already received my data from the backend and everything is fine now. BTW i posted the answer to my problem i found the issue today even though it was a dumb issue 

Comment: Using React like this is still invalid and will cause problems sooner or later

Comment: I know but in this situation I had to, because with use states and asyn data the backend was sending infinite messages and the server was shut down everytime. I tried to make it worked and asked here on stackoverflow if someone know why this issue was happening and unfortunatly no one could help.

Comment: I just ran into problems already :p